# VS 2013 keeps saying that "String" is undefined, i'm not sure whats wrong with it

Tags: string, namespaces, c++-cli

I'm not really sure what its meaning that the string is undefined, I've tried to google it but all that comes up is just random stuff about strings.

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include "String"

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
int main(cli::array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Organizer1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Comment: Try `string` in lower case. Also, if you intend to use the C++std Strings, you should be writing as `#include<string>`.

Comment: Do you mean [`System::String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class `String` is defined in the namesapce `System`

So either write

```
using namespace System;
```

or use qualified name

```
int main(cli::array<System::String^>^ args)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry about not accepting earlier, my internet went out for a while but this worked! Thank you so much for your time.